# Errno2 xml syntax in launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i launch gazebo_worlds/empty_worlds via cmd it starts
but with a launch file below:

it shows following error:
while processing /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/empty_world.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/empty_world.launch'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12921/errno2-xml-syntax-in-launch-file/) by [ila](https://answers.ros.org/users/1749/ila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message is telling you that /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/empty_world.launch doesn't exist. If you do

```
ls /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/empty_world.launch
```

what does it say? Can you verify that simulator_gazebo is installed correctly?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on 2015-10-13**:
if i execute ls, it says "ls: cannot access (file path): No such file or directory"..i tried for other existing launch files, and i get the same file path(successful access) as entered...what could be the problem?

**Comment by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on 2015-10-13**:
Sorry, my mistake...(there was a space between launch and xml that i missed while editing file)...thank you, your solution worked....thanks...